# Spring Integration ByteArrayRawSerializer TCP Client Server

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I'm trying to create a TCP/IP simulator that mimics a production server that I'm not able to test against. The server receives and sends byte arrays - not strings.

In using Spring Integration, I'm able to have a conversation that works fine when not using the ByteArrayRawSerializer, but when I implement the ByteArrayRawSerializer, I'm not able to receive messages back to the client even though they're being processed on the server.

The Transformers.objectToString() method seems to be suspect, but at this point I believe I've tried most everything. Please advise...

The important client code is as follows:

```
    @Bean
    FailoverClientConnectionFactory failoverClientFactory() {
        FailoverClientConnectionFactory failoverClientConnectionFactory = new FailoverClientConnectionFactory(underlyingCF());
        failoverClientConnectionFactory.isSingleUse();
        return failoverClientConnectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public List<AbstractClientConnectionFactory> underlyingCF() {

        List<AbstractClientConnectionFactory> connections = new ArrayList<AbstractClientConnectionFactory>();
        TcpNioClientConnectionFactory primary = new TcpNioClientConnectionFactory(primaryTcpServerHost, primaryTcpServerPort);
        primary.isSingleUse();
        primary.setSerializer(new ByteArrayRawSerializer());  // Works when not present
        primary.setDeserializer(new ByteArrayRawSerializer()); // Works when not present
        log.info("Starting with Primary Server/Port as: {}:{}", primaryTcpServerHost, primaryTcpServerPort);

        TcpNioClientConnectionFactory failover = new TcpNioClientConnectionFactory(secondaryTcpServerHost, secondaryTcpServerPort);
        failover.isSingleUse();
        failover.setSerializer(new ByteArrayRawSerializer());  // Works when not present
        failover.setDeserializer(new ByteArrayRawSerializer());  // Works when not present
        log.info("Starting with Secondary Server/Port as: {}:{}", secondaryTcpServerHost, secondaryTcpServerPort);

        connections.add(primary);
        connections.add(failover);

        return connections;
    }

    @Bean
    @DependsOn("failoverClientFactory")
    public IntegrationFlow liveMumClient() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(Gate.class)
                .handle(Tcp.outboundGateway(failoverClientFactory()))
                .transform(Transformers.objectToString())
                .get();
    }

    public interface Gate {
        // TODO: Use properties for 20000 seems to be unsupported 
        @Gateway(replyTimeout = 20000)
        String sendAndReceive(byte[] out);
    }
```

And the server configuration is:

```
@Configuration
public class LiveMumTcpConfig {

    @Value("${tcp.server.port}")
    private Integer tcpServerPort;

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow server() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(
                Tcp.inboundGateway(Tcp.netServer(tcpServerPort)
                        .deserializer(new ByteArrayRawSerializer()) // Works when not present
                        .serializer(new ByteArrayRawSerializer()) // Works when not present
                        ))
                .transform(new MessageTransformer())
                .log()
                .handle((p, h) -> {
                    Object retVal;
                    try {
                        retVal = LiveMumTcpHandler.handle(p);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                    return retVal;
                })
                .get();
    }
}
```

And... I'm getting the following output:

Client-Side

```
2019-12-03 17:31:03.284  INFO 30587 --- [   scheduling-1] gov.nyc.mumweb.service.MumWebService     : Sending Generated XML <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><STARFIRECAD sequenceNumber="20191203/17310327410"><polling><date>20191203</date><time>17:31:03</time></polling></STARFIRECAD>
2019-12-03 17:31:03.336  WARN 30587 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.i.i.tcp.connection.TcpNioConnection  : No publisher available to publish TcpConnectionOpenEvent [source=TcpNioConnection:unknown:0:-1:acec6b6d-0b74-49e1-87ca-f3344cb4cc08], [factory=unknown, connectionId=unknown:0:-1:acec6b6d-0b74-49e1-87ca-f3344cb4cc08] **OPENED**
2019-12-03 17:31:13.340  WARN 30587 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.i.i.tcp.connection.TcpNioConnection  : No publisher available to publish TcpConnectionCloseEvent [source=TcpNioConnection:unknown:0:-1:acec6b6d-0b74-49e1-87ca-f3344cb4cc08], [factory=unknown, connectionId=unknown:0:-1:acec6b6d-0b74-49e1-87ca-f3344cb4cc08] **CLOSED**
2019-12-03 17:31:13.341 ERROR 30587 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.i.ip.tcp.TcpOutboundGateway          : Tcp Gateway exception

java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.integration.MessageTimeoutException: Timed out waiting for response, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=byte[166], headers={replyChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@2394a155, errorChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@2394a155, id=f58e889b-786b-37e3-6c0b-0abf88337e0c, timestamp=1575422199215}]
    at gov.nyc.mumweb.service.MumWebService.heartbeat(MumWebService.java:44) ~[classes/:na]
    at gov.nyc.mumweb.config.LiveMumHeartbeatConfig$Runner.run(LiveMumHeartbeatConfig.java:36) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:84) ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_141]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308) [na:1.8.0_141]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [na:1.8.0_141]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294) [na:1.8.0_141]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_141]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_141]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_141]
Caused by: org.springframework.integration.MessageTimeoutException: Timed out waiting for response
    at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.TcpOutboundGateway.getReply(TcpOutboundGateway.java:216) ~[spring-integration-ip-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.TcpOutboundGateway.handleRequestMessage(TcpOutboundGateway.java:161) ~[spring-integration-ip-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:127) ~[spring-integration-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:170) ~[spring-integration-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:115) ~[spring-integration-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:133) ~[spring-integration-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:106) ~[spring-integration-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:73) ~[spring-integration-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:453) ~[spring-integration-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:403) ~[spring-integration-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187) ~[spring-messaging-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSendAndReceive(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:233) ~[spring-messaging-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSendAndReceive(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47) ~[spring-messaging-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessagingTemplate.sendAndReceive(AbstractMessagingTemplate.java:46) ~[spring-messaging-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.sendAndReceive(MessagingTemplate.java:97) ~[spring-integration-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.sendAndReceive(MessagingTemplate.java:38) ~[spring-integration-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessagingTemplate.convertSendAndReceive(AbstractMessagingTemplate.java:96) ~[spring-messaging-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessagingTemplate.convertSendAndReceive(AbstractMessagingTemplate.java:86) ~[spring-messaging-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.doSendAndReceive(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:495) ~[spring-integration-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.sendAndReceive(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:469) ~[spring-integration-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.sendOrSendAndReceive(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:564) ~[spring-integration-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.invokeGatewayMethod(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:489) ~[spring-integration-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.doInvoke(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:464) ~[spring-integration-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.invoke(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:453) ~[spring-integration-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy100.sendAndReceive(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at gov.nyc.mumweb.service.MumWebService.heartbeat(MumWebService.java:39) ~[classes/:na]
    ... 14 common frames omitted
```

Server Side:

```
GenericMessage [payload=<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>< ... >, headers={replyChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@3e5610e3, errorChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@3e5610e3, ip_tcp_remotePort=51898, ip_connectionId=localhost:51898:8077:e2c7776b-3f60-45b5-8433-031f094bbefe, ip_localInetAddress=/127.0.0.1, ip_address=127.0.0.1, id=4dca4f70-5c12-0be4-96bb-26188cc90f71, ip_hostname=localhost, timestamp=1575419803630}]
```

Comment: Is there a causes by In the  stack trace?

Comment: Yes. I please see my updated posting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TCP is a stream - you need something to tell the receiver what constitutes a "message" within that stream. The raw deserializer uses the socket closing to delimit the message.

You can't use a raw deserializer on the server side with a gateway because the client closing the socket means we can't send the reply.

You can use a raw serializer on the server side for the reply, as long as the `singleUseConnections` property is set so the gateway will close the connection when the reply is sent, so the client side will get the EOF.

Since you control both the client and server side, why do you want to use the raw (de)serializer?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Gary. I'm writing a simulator to mimic a legacy tcp/ip api. It sends packets with the protocol being : 
STX 
PAYLOAD 
ETX 

Where STX is a byte value of 2 and ETX is a byte value of 3. The payload is a string. That's pretty much it. So, what would you suggest for Serializers/Deserializers in this case?

Comment: I saw the ByteArrayStxEtxSerializer class. Initial results are positive. I'll post an answer tomorrow. Gary, thanks! You're comment got me on the right track!